# Why using a ESP01 adapter?

Tags: wifi

I bought an ESP-01 adapter (initially I thought this was the WIFI module):

[ESP-01 adapter](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/ESP8266-Serial-WiFi-Wireless-ESP-01-Adapter-Module-3-3V-5V-Compatible-For-Arduino/32740663668.html?spm=2114.13010608.0.0.90dm9a)

Than I bought the 'real'  ESP-01 (which is not arrived yet):

[ESP-01](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/Cr2032-battery-3v-cr2032-lithium-battery-button-cell-battery-electronic-2032-battery-electronic/1678385231.html?spm=2114.13010608.0.0.wrwcB5)

However, according to this link: [connect](http://domoticx.com/esp8266-wifi-esp-01-module-aansluiten/) (sorry it's in Dutch), but the picture shows that the ESP-01 is directly connected to the 3.3V of the Arduino.

My question: why bother using the adapter card? Or does it give additional security/protection (and what)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an ESP8266 with a traditional Arduino requires logic level translation of the UART signal. That is what this adaptor provides. It also provides a dedicated 5V -> 3.3V voltage regulator so you don't stress the Arduino's rather underpowered 3.3V regulator.

The two SOT-23 components are N-channel MOSFETs (probably BSS138P or similar), and the SOT-89 component is the voltage regulator.

Yes, you can provide all that yourself, to varying levels of complexity - this just makes things easier. And since you already have it you may as well make use of it.

Comment: Thank you very much ... I assume with logic level translation you mean also a 5V-3.3V translation (but for the data?) ... I will start using both than ... but eventually I will need more (thanks to your good idea to use multiple Arduinos).

Comment: Yes, the logic level translation converts the 5V TX from the Arduino into the 3.3V RX of the ESP8266, and the 3.3V TX of the ESP8266 into a 5V RX to the Arduino (the latter is not strictly needed, but helps to improve noise immunity).

Comment: Ah thanks .. and that probably explains also why sometimes I read RX needs to be connected to TX and vice versa instead of RX<->RX and TX<->TX

Comment: You connect RX->RX and TX->TX if you are using the Arduino as a UART interface (disabling the ATMeag328P by holding reset LOW or physically removing the chip). Otherwise you connect RX to TX and TX to RX (the Arduino pins in this latter case are usually chosen by you and used with SoftwareSerial since the UART pins are used by your USB connection).

Comment: Are software pins (meaning non RX and TX on Arduino) fast enough for WIFI speeds (like Mb/s), using software serial?

Comment: Mbps? No. But then neither is the ESP8266 - it usually runs no faster than 115200 baud. If you want high speed communication like that then you need a PC.

Comment: Ok ... I think 115kbps is enough, just wondering how much I lose if I use software serial ... but I will test it when I have the ESP-01 :-)

Comment: What is it you are hoping to do with it?

Comment: For two reasons actually: 1) make a PC application to send information to an Arduino ... this is not time critical (max 128 KB to be sent). 2) sending information between multiple Arduinos, close together (like 1 meter approximately), not much data, but time critical (sending information back and forth within preferably 1 ms, size like 5-25 bytes average).

Comment: How are you thinking of getting the Arduino to process the 128KB of data? No "normal" Arduino can store that much information for processing.

Comment: The 128 KB will be put into a 23LC1024 SRAM ... (I already tested it by copying it from an SD card). To prevent every Arduino to have its own 128KB I want to make one ' controller' Arduino with 128KB SRAM and the other Arduino's send/receive (processed) messages using that 128KB

Comment: Ok, that's fine then. As long as you have that covered. You'll have to "chunk up" your transfer, of course, into a number of smaller requests for the Arduino to process.

Comment: Yes the requests will be around 5-25 bytes .. for SysEx messages I might need more, but those will not be time critical (and need to be chunked up. My biggest worry is the speed for the small messages, but if that doesn't work I can use RS232 connector/cables (but WIFI is more convenient, although the distance is very small). RF is another option but I need a lot of extra items (receiver/transmitter), IR is impossible (line of sight).

Comment: you won't get 1ms times with wifi. i think my best half-legs are about 15ms. this is due to http overhead

Comment: @dandavis thanks for this info ... that means wifi is not possible (back for analysing a wired connection probably).

Comment: Unless you program the ESP8266 module(s) directly and get them to talk MIDI directly from their UART pins - then use UDP to transfer datagrams at much higher speed and lower latency.

Comment: Hmm, the adapter I got only has a single ceramic disc capacitor, none of the other stuff.  It also has eight pins instead of four, so it's barely anything at all. I guess you really have to be careful when ordering from Chinese sellers on eBay.

Comment: The anonymous downvoter strikes again.