# Which connection should I use (preferably wireless)?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, arduino-mega, midi

For a (for now MIDI only) project I was planning to use multiple Arduinos and send messages around.

However, for the latency, I can have max 10ms (to prevent audible delay).

I hoped to use WIFI modules (ESP-01), however, according to a previous question in [Question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/38988/why-using-a-esp01-adapter), one remark that due to HTTP overhead the time/latency would be 15 ms. So that means WIFI is not possible.

My requirements:

- Latency of <= 3 ms (rationale: I need at least 5 ms for processing, and want to keep total latency < 10 ms)
- Preferably a wireless solution (rationale: I want to add later more Arduinos and want to prevent cabling)
- Preferably not using a hardware serial (low prio requirement) (rationale: the MIDI box which is a Mega, would preferably need 4 MIDI inputs, using a hardware serial would reduce one, software serial is unacceptable for MIDI).

Situation:

- Arduinos are very close together, probably within centimeters (upto like 50 centimeters)
- Messages are short (like 5-10 bytes max)
- Burst of messages can be possible, but not so likely

Background/message flow:

- Receiving MIDI input by Arduino 1
- Sending (filtered/changed) message to Arduino 2
- Arduino 2 process the manage, takes <= 5 ms
- Arduino 2 sends message back to Arduino 1
- Arduino 1 converts it to a MIDI message and sends back

This all needs to be done within <= 10 ms

**My thoughts so far:**

Wireless solutions:

- WIFI: HTTP seems to result in 15 ms delays, which is against my requirement.
- RF: probably overkill since my Arduinos will be very near to each other. Also I would need both a receiver and transmitter in both Arduino's.
- IR: Due to out-of-sight problems not very convenient.

Wired solutions:

- I2C: Might be possible, planning to use later also an I2C display possibly but should not be a problem
- SPI: On Arduino 2, I'm already using an SRAM with SPI which I do not want to stress more (also a time-critical resource). Also an SD card via SPI is used (but this is not a time critical resource).
- Wire: Not checked yet

**Question**
Is there any wireless (or wired) solution I can use (probably beyond the ones I analyzed)?

115200 baud is what I need for a Serial connection, probably a SPI/I2C (latter preferred) is also acceptable. Or I might have missed other communication possibilities.

Comment: NRF24L01+ transceiver, maybe.

Comment: You need a custom solution.  I was looking into wireless flash sync signals years ago and everything off the shelf took too long.  If you do go with Ethernet (I think you shouldn't) you probably need to understand the difference between UDP and TCP.  One is "get it there now no matter what the condition the packet is in" (skype).  The other is "keep trying until it is perfect" (bank transactions).

Comment: @Gerben: I checked and it seems 250KBPS is possible ... which is strange, since close WIFI has a max of 115baud... I don't need the long distance, but if the speed/latency is good, it might be a good candidate.

Comment: Also, keep in mind I2C and SPI are for chip to chip communications.  Neither were meant to go any distance.  The are really to keep the pin counts low on the integrated circuit packages.  Which is a good way to keep the MTBF (time between failures) down.

Comment: @st2000 I heard that default WIFI (and Ethernet probably) using HTTP request takes a lot of overhead. Currently I don't know much bout UDP/TCP and I do not want to spend TOO much time learning that (since my core project also needs to continue).

Comment: @st2000 I thought I2C was for connecting (many) devices (so distance is not so much a problem). But if needed, I will keep distance low (but still like 10-30 centimeters).

Comment: Yes, Ethernet is way more complex than most people make it out to be.  And on top of everything else, it is very possible that no two Ethernet appliances work alike adding to the frustrations.  Synchronization over Ethernet is not trivial.  I suspect Sonos and Logitech/SqueezBox both use an extensive bag of tricks to synchronize music played at multiple points off an Ethenet network.  I would stick to MIDI and investigate if there are wireless MIDI appliances available.  After all MIDI was created with music in mind.

Comment: @st2000 actually I do not want to send MIDI messages wireless, but my own messages (although they contain some of the MIDI info). However, maybe I can use it as a low-latency (using MIDI as protocol to send info, possibly even MIDI messages itself).

Comment: I2C can be used for multiple devices. But normally all are on the same board.  For example, you computer mother board may have several I2C temperature sensors all connected to a common I2C bus.

Comment: you can use a fiber optic link to connect IR and make it act more like a wire if you have line of sight issues. You can also just do 115200 serial between devices. The ESP8266 can use `Serial`, and `Serial1` (for TX only), these are hardware, so you should be able to daisy-chain at high speed.

Comment: @st2000 ah ok ... well in my case I just need commands sending from one Arduino to another, so than I2C is maybe not so good.

Comment: @dandavis: a fiber optic link, never thought about that ... and plan 115200 serial might do as well. Do you mean that with an ESP8266 I can skip http and use Serial 'directly'?

Comment: that's exactly what i mean; they are very low overhead and latency

Comment: Beyond the nRF24L01's I also ordered an extra ESP-01 (ESP8266) so I can try to send messages between them and make the best choice.

Comment: I see the anonymous downvoter is back. For everybody else a nice christmas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would either use the ESP8266 as a standalone device and directly program it to work with UDP datagrams or a permanently established TCP socket, or the nRF24L01+.

Of the two I would most likely use the nRF24L01+. It's good enough for 99% of wireless keyboards and mice, so plenty good enough for a few MIDI style messages.

Comment: Well I might need quite some MIDI messages (like CC messages), but that sounds good ... need to analyze both in more depth (and need to order an nRF24L01+).

Comment: You'll want at least two nRF24L01 modules :P

Comment: I ordered 5 SE8R01's (they seem to be compatible) and 5 adapter plates (for NRF24L01+) ... together < 4 euro.